# SSRS custom code and variables life

Tags: sql, reporting-services, tfs, report

I have a report that needs to process the data that it get from SQL before show it.
For that, I have a custom code, and a Dictionary where I push all the processed data. 
My problem is that if I save the dictionary in a report variable when I export the report to Word that variable seems to be cleaned.
What is the lifecycle of the reports variables? What is the most convenient way of saving an object during the report life.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you research and find so far? Which blogposts, bits of documentation, etc. say something about this?

Comment: I have searched a lot about this. One possible solution is to create a HashTable<InstanceId, myDictionary> as a shared variable in the custom code. That Hash could contains all the data of all the executions of the report, and use a key to identify what instance is active. I don't really like that approach. Reading some blogs, I think that the problem could be the "process on demand" approach of SSRS 2008. That renders the report every time you export it. The problem is that I cannot undertand or find an accurate variable cycle life explanation and why it looses the value. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing around with custom code for a about 6 weeks so I can answer some parts of the question of variable lifecycle in SSRS 2008 R2.

I have report that uses a Dictionary  to store totals, allows me provide some specialist subtotals for financial stuff.  I have something you can check (as I can't yet comment on things).

Have you declared the variable as 'shared', this is a custom code specific keyword that doesn't translate into VB.net.  It ensures the variable lives to the next page,  I tested this to Excel and word seemed to work fine transferring over the variable's data.

There is a trade off however under SSRS "report on demand" engine (on web, but not on BIDS) it holds the variable and doesn't garbage collect until the cache itself is cleared.  I wrote some more custom code to indicate when my parameters changed and clears the variable.

Code;

```
Public Shared Dim Totals As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)

Public Function WipeKeys() as Decimal 'Clear Data from Dictionary (this will clear the cached object as well)
  Totals.Clear()
  Return 0D
End Function
```

I will also to recommend overwrite the key where ever possible to ensure reduction of addition loops.

Regards,

Comment: Hi ChallengeAccepted, Thanks a lot for your reply! I was trying to avoid the use of statics variables because of the garbage and to avoid race-conditions. But It seems to be the only way of do it. I'm still wondering why SSRS cleans SOME of the locals variables and not all of them (or none of them). Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, I have had to deal with a OLE DB data source that refuses the idea of grouping and aggregates.  So I have begin quite akin with these :)